# Get total values_count from a dataframe with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python pandas dataframe with several columns. Now I want to copy all values into one single column to get a values_count result alle values included. At the end I need the total count of string1, string2, n. What is the best way to do it?

```
index row 1    row 2   ...
0     string1  string3
1     string1  string1
2     string2  string2
...
```

Comment: What would the output be for your example? 3?

Comment: string1 3, string2 2, string3 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If performance is an issue try:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(df.values.ravel())
#Counter({'string1': 3, 'string2': 2, 'string3': 1})
```

Or `stack` it into one `Series` then use `value_counts`

```
df.stack().value_counts()
#string1    3
#string2    2
#string3    1
#dtype: int64
```

For larger (long) DataFrames with a small number of columns, looping may be faster than stacking:

```
s = pd.Series()
for col in df.columns:
    s = s.add(df[col].value_counts(), fill_value=0)

#string1    3.0
#string2    2.0
#string3    1.0
#dtype: float64
```

Also, there's a numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(df.to_numpy(), return_counts=True)

#(array(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'], dtype=object),
# array([3, 2, 1], dtype=int64))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'row1': ['string1', 'string1', 'string2'],
                   'row2': ['string3', 'string1', 'string2']})

def vc_from_loop(df):
    s = pd.Series()
    for col in df.columns:
        s = s.add(df[col].value_counts(), fill_value=0)
    return s
```

#### Small `DataFrame`

```
%timeit Counter(df.values.ravel())
#11.1 µs ± 56.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit df.stack().value_counts()
#835 µs ± 5.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit vc_from_loop(df)
#2.15 ms ± 34.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.unique(df.to_numpy(), return_counts=True)
#23.8 µs ± 241 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### Long `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.concat([df]*300000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit Counter(df.values.ravel())
#124 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.stack().value_counts()
#337 ms ± 3.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit vc_from_loop(df)
#182 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.unique(df.to_numpy(), return_counts=True)
#1.16 s ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: You might find `df.values.ravel()` slightly more efficient.