# Count number of values in an entire DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have DataFrame with 50 columns and around 50000 rows. I'm trying to find the total amount of times a value (e.g. 2) appears in the entire DataFrame.

The DataFrame only contains values between 0 to 7. I am able to execute the code for a single column using this:

```
print(df['col1'].value_counts())
```

I then attempted to create a for loop like the one shown below:

```
for cols in df:
    print(df[cols].value_counts())
```

This works, but it prints it out as individual results for each column.

Instead of having the results split up per column, I'm trying to get something like what's shown below, but for all the columns in the DataFrame combined and not just 1 column.

```
val    no.
7.0    165
3.0    127
5.0     118
6.0     112
2.0      98
4.0      88
1.0      64
0.0      21
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `(df.values == 2).sum()`?

Comment: This is embarrassing. Do you want to answer that so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either  for a specific value:

```
(df.values == 2).sum()
```

or for all:

```
np.unique(df.values, return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

You may need check with 1st `stack` then `value_counts` and now you can select what you need from index

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: It's super interesting. I find that for object columns, and a large DataFrame `Counter` is far faster [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018311/get-total-values-count-from-a-dataframe-with-python-pandas/52018446#52018446), yet for integer columns `stack` can be 2x as fast.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

print(pd.DataFrame(Counter(df.values.flatten()), index=['Count']).T)
```