# Pandas, DataFrame unique values from few columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count uniqiue values that are in few columns. My data frame looks like that:

```
Name      Name.1    Name.2    Name.3
x         z          c          y
y         p          q          x
q         p           a         y
```

Output should looks like below:

```
x   2
z   1
c   1
y   3
q   2
p   2
a   1
```

I used a groupby or count_values but couldn't get a correct output. Any ideas ? Thanks All !

Comment: you can simply stack and count i.e  `df.stack().value_counts()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total values\_count from a dataframe with Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018311/get-total-values-count-from-a-dataframe-with-python-pandas). Also contains timings which may be relevant for your object type `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want to consider values regardless of their row or column location. In that case you should collapse the dataframe and just use Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

arr = np.array(df)
count = Counter(arr.reshape(arr.size))
```

Comment: It work's great. Thanks mate ! Do you have a idea how to show for instance 5 results that occurs the most often ?

Comment: `sorted(count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: It returns empty list

Comment: Sorry which one? The sorted result or count?

Comment: Count is all right and I see that you changed your second answer and sorted shows all results. Not the first 5 that occurs the most often

Comment: You can do `sorted(..., reverse=True)[:5]` to get the top five by occurrence

Comment: no need mate, that all I need :D Thank you one more time for your time

Answer (score 0):

Another ([Pandas-based](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)) approach is to [(Series) `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) [`value_counts` to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589877/4057186) and then take the sum (column-wise)

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
print(df2.sum(axis=1).astype(int)
a    1
c    1
p    2
q    2
x    2
y    3
z    1
dtype: int32
```