# How to use pd.Series.value_counts across several columns in a dataframe to get totals?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a toy dataset with a dataframe in Pandas that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is create a series from this, that lists all of the unique interests with a total next to each of how many users like them. Something like this:

[image]

I've tried different ways to differing degrees of success/failure, but not got to what I need. I'd appreciate it if anyone could throw me a hint on this. Thanks!

Comment: `df.stack().value_counts().to_dict()`

Comment: Thank you sir. That is both illuminating and frustrating in equal measure.

Comment: Other options too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018311/get-total-values-count-from-a-dataframe-with-python-pandas.